# Module function definition in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby with version 1.9.3, folllowing the tutorial on LearnRubyTheHardWay.

It seems like when you define a function within a `Module`, you have to prefix the function name with the module's name, like this:

```
module MyStuff
    def MyStuff.apple()
        puts "I AM APPLES!"
    end
end

MyStuff.apple()
```

Why can't you just do this:

```
module MyStuff
    def apple()
        puts "I AM APPLES!"
    end
end

MyStuff.apple() # this does not work
```

In the Ruby docs, there's [an example like the one above](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html).

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Simply because it's a Module and no class. You're probably looking for the factory pattern?

Comment: @BenjaminM Making MyStuff a class instead of a module doesn’t change this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules are a way of grouping together methods, classes, and constants. Modules give you two major benefits:
Modules provide a namespace and prevent name clashes.
Modules implement the mixin facility.

Taken from (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm)

You can instead do:

```
module MyStuff
    def self.apple
        puts "I AM APPLES!"
    end
end

MyStuff.apple # "I AM APPLES!"
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you created a class-level method meaning you can call it directly on the class/module : `MyStuff.apple`. In the second one you created an instance-level method, meaning you'll need an instance to access the method :

```
class MyKlazz
    include MyStuff
end

obj=MyKlazz.new
obj.apple
```

Answer (score 2):

That’s because you’re defining `apple` as an *instance method* on MyStuff, and since MyStuff is not an instance of itself, you cannot call `apple` on it.

In order to call `apple`, you have a few options:

- Define the method on `MyStuff` explicitly, as you’ve found:

  ```
  module MyStuff
    def MyStuff.apple
      puts "I AM APPLES!"
    end
  end

  MyStuff.apple  #=> "I AM APPLES!"
  ```

  but you don’t have to be *this* explicit, and can use `self` instead of `MyStuff`:

  ```
  module MyStuff
    def self.apple
      puts "I AM APPLES!"
    end
  end

  MyStuff.apple  #=> "I AM APPLES!"
  ```
- You can `include` MyStuff into a class and call the method on an instance of that class:

  ```
  module MyStuff
    def apple
      puts "I AM APPLES!"
    end
  end

  class Foo; include MyStuff; end

  Foo.new.apple  #=> "I AM APPLES!"
  ```
- You can `extend` MyStuff into a class or module—this includes MyStuff itself:

  ```
  module MyStuff
    extend self

    def apple
      puts "I AM APPLES!"
    end
  end

  MyStuff.apple  #=> "I AM APPLES!"

  module OtherStuff; extend MyStuff; end

  OtherStuff.apple  #=> "I AM APPLES!"
  ```

This is very similar to how classes work. For example, this doesn’t work either:

```
class Foo
  def bar; 42; end
end

Foo.bar  #=> #<NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for Foo:Class>
```

because `bar` is, again, an instance method, so you need to create an instance or make `bar` a class method:

```
class Foo
  def bar; 42; end
  def self.bar; 24; end
end

Foo.bar      #=> 24
Foo.new.bar  #=> 42
```

Answer (score 1):

The first example ...

```
module MyStuff
  def MyStuff.apple()
    puts "I AM APPLES!"
  end
end
```

... works because you're defining the method ON the module instead of IN the module, which is what you're doing with the second example:

```
module MyStuff
  def apple()
    puts "I AM APPLES!"
  end
end
```

It's similar to if you had a class and did the same thing:

```
class Conrad
  def Conrad.apple()
    puts "I AM APPLES"
  end
end
```

You can also use `def self.apple()`, which means the same:

```
class Conrad
  def self.apple()
    puts "I AM APPLES"
  end
end
```

In both cases, you're defining a method on the class itself rather than instances of that class.

In the case of a module, you're defining a method that would be available to a class if you extended that class (i.e. `Conrad.apple`) or that class's instances if you included it instead (i.e. `Conrad.new.apple`).